# Base Class Serialization Issue - do not serialize Derived Class Properties

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am tiring to serialize a fairly large list of entities, that are all derived from a base class.
I only need the base class properties in the client.  How do I achieve this without instantiating a new instance of the base class?

I have tried creating a custom ContractResolver, but it seems that it does a getType() at runtime, instead of using the Type of the list/Array being serialized

See code sample below.

I want to achieve. castBaseString  == actualBaseString ;

So I want castBaseString to = `[{"Id":1},{"Id":2}]` not `[{"Value":"value","Id":1},{"Value":"value2","Id":2}]`

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace Tests {

    [TestClass]
    public class JsonNetTest {
        class Base {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        class Derived : Base {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
        
        class OtherDerived : Base {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string OtherValue { get; set; }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test() {
            IEnumerable<Derived> deriveds = new Derived[] {
                new Derived {Id = 1, Value = "value" },
                new Derived {Id = 2, Value = "value2" }
            };

            IEnumerable<Base> castBases = deriveds.Cast<Base>().ToList();

            IEnumerable<Base> bases = new Base[] {
                new Base {Id = 1 },
                new Base {Id = 2 }
            };
            JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings();

            var derString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deriveds, s);
            var castBaseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(castBases, s);
            var actualBaseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bases, s);

            Assert.AreEqual(actualBaseString, castBaseString);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(castBaseString, derString);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**
Additional Context:
I just posted this simple test case for clarity.
the actual context this is being used is in an aspnet core application.

Consider there are 3 controllers

1. /api/DerivedController/
2. /api/OtherDerivedController/
3. /api/BaseController/

when a client calls 1, we want to return a list of *Derived*, when a client calls
2 we want to return a list of *OtherDerived* when they call 3, we want to return a list of *Base*

The data is stored in 2 different tables in the database TBL_DERIVED and TBL_OTHERDERIVED.

What we want to achieve when they call base is to return data from One or both of these tables, but just the common properties of these tables.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible the way the json serialization works.
@stuartd answer might be a good workaround if you only have limited cases you want to do this for.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use attributes, you *can* use a ContractResolver to force only properties from `Base` to be serialized:

```cs
public class DerivedTypeFilterContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.DeclaringType != typeof(T)) {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
        }
        
        return property;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```cs
void Main() {

    IEnumerable<Derived> deriveds = new Derived[] {
                new Derived {Id = 1, Value = "value" },
                new Derived {Id = 2, Value = "value2" }
            };

    IEnumerable<Base> castBases = deriveds.Cast<Base>().ToList();

    IEnumerable<Base> bases = new Base[] {
                new Base {Id = 1 },
                new Base {Id = 2 }
            };

    JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        ContractResolver = new DerivedTypeFilterContractResolver<Base>()
    };

    var derString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deriveds, s);
    var castBaseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(castBases, s);
    var actualBaseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bases, s);

    Console.WriteLine(castBaseString);
}


class Base {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```json
[{"Id":1},{"Id":2}]
```

Comment: This is all fine, but now the second assert  fails, because when serializing, Derived, it serializes them to '[{"Id":1},{"Id":2}]' , omitting the Derived.Value field.

Comment: Also, if you now serialize any other object that does not derive from Base, they will all be '[{},{}]'

Comment: Well, yes. You'd only use this resolver when you only want the base class values.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do that in a aspnet core project. I'm pretty sure the Contract resolver is cached at startup and you can't change it at runtime for performance reasons.  I will see if something like this will work : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/05/setting-json-serialization-configuration-at-runtime-on-a-net-core-api/

Comment: _Any thoughts on how to do that in a aspnet core project.?_ - you'll have to give more details about that. You asked _I am trying to serialize a fairly large list of entities, that are all derived from a base class. I only need the base class properties in the client._ and using this contract resolver does just that. But now you're saying you only want to do this 'sometimes'? Which times, exactly? And surely you have control over the serialization process, and you can do what you want?

Comment: Thanks. see edit above for additional context. I was trying to keep the problem simple

Answer (score 0):

Add `[JsonIgnore]` top of property.

```
class Derived : Base {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to attribute `Derived` class with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` to exclude all properties by default (no need to mark them all with `JsonIgnoreAttribute`).

Comment: For other specific calls, I do want to serialize, the value, but not when serializing the base class.

Comment: Also, I have no options to add Attributes to the types I am working with as it is a third party Data Model.